# Assert exception raised due to previous test-case failure

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, junit, assert

I can not think of a better heading.

In the following code, if `rollBackLogger` is `nil`, the first test case would fail but all other test cases would raise an exception.

Is there a way available to avoid this, other than using an `if` statement?

I believe that this is a very common situation for unit testing and that there should be some function in `assert` or some other way around to avoid this.

```
assert.NotNil(rollbackLogger)
assert.Equal("Action", rollBackLogger[0].Action)
assert.Equal("random path", rollBackLogger[0].FilePath)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `t.FailNow()` if you want the test to fail if the condition isn't valid.

I don't think there's a way to stop the test on an assert failure without using a condition or an external package.

```
if !assert.NotNil(rollbackLogger) {
    t.FailNow()
}
assert.Equal("Action", rollBackLogger[0].Action)
assert.Equal("random path", rollBackLogger[0].FilePath)
```

or if you use the `testify/assert` package,

```
if !assert.NotNil(rollbackLogger) {
    assert.FailNow(t, "message")
}
assert.Equal("Action", rollBackLogger[0].Action)
assert.Equal("random path", rollBackLogger[0].FilePath)
```

Comment: You can also use `assert.FailNow(t)` to do the same, but I don't see it being any upgrade over `t.FailNow()` exept for sticking to one "assertion" source within a test.

Answer (score 5):

Use [require.NotNil](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/require#NotNil) instead.

> Package require implements the same assertions as the `assert` package but stops test execution when a test fails.

require.NoError is also particularly useful.